# python How do i store the [code] in url/code=xxx so i can pass it to a function

Tags: python, function, variables, oauth-2.0, foursquare

Halo Devs.

I want to get an Foursquare access_token.

Foursquare sends a code in this formart:

'[http://www.example.net/auth?code=Z0NJ55C4BUX4DIMNCHRSVSIIPBEBD4TGOD45J3IZNVNVAIFZ#*=*](http://www.example.net/auth?code=Z0NJ55C4BUX4DIMNCHRSVSIIPBEBD4TGOD45J3IZNVNVAIFZ#_=_)'

I want to store the code parameter value so i may exchange the code I got for an access token.

What code can i use to save the code parameter in a variable?

Here are the instructions by Foursquare: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication

Comment: What do you mean by "code parameter value"?

Comment: can you try to tackle the problem and show us your code? How can we help you if you don't have something to show?